# Deno : Create bare hand HTTP Server: Deno.read keeps reading the connection

Tags: deno

I was trying to a build a HTTP server using deno, but my code seems to misbehave

```
const listner = Deno.listen({port: 3000});
const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
for await(var conn of listner){
    var p = new Uint8Array(1000);
    while(await Deno.read(conn.rid,p)){
        console.log(decoder.decode(p));
    }
    console.log("While loop ended");
    conn.write(encoder.encode("Hello"));
    conn.close();
}
```

The code never reaches "While loop ended".
As Deno.read must return null when there is nothing to read.
I do not want to use the standard lib http server.

I wanted to do create it from scratch as I wanted to understand its working.
Please can you cite me how one will create bare hello world HTTP server, by simply reading the world request and then sending hello world response ?

Comment: have you closed the connection on the client side?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande My client is browser!, it auto connects and disconnects!